# Four lots of sums using only $4$

Tags: arithmetic

You need to make exactly four sums using only the number $4$ each time.  For example, $4+4+4+4 = 16$ or $4×4-4÷4 = 3$.

You can use $+ - × ÷$, square, or square root.  Another example: $4^2 × 4 + 4 ÷ 4 = 17$.

Now, how do you make the number $18$?

Comment: Can we use parentheses? What is the order of operations?

Comment: $4^2 × 4 + 4 ÷ 4 = 65$ unless you put in some parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

How about the following:

$$4^2+\sqrt{4}+4-4$$

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_fours) gives $18=4 \times 4 + 4 - \sqrt 4 = \frac {44}{\sqrt 4}-4$  Normally squares are not permitted because of the digit $2$.